# hover isnt refreshed with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have color-switcher on my website.I am new at js and jquery but I wrote its code.Simply, it changes css information to change colors and background colors and their hovers.

but my color switcher doesnt change hover colors after first changing.

so, if you notice below youtube video ( screen shot ), after first sliding, brown colors doesnt come again.the brown color property gone.

you can check or work on my website:

https://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/-

Here is YOUTUBE video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0wkBpgMNjo&feature=youtu.be

how can I fix it?

here is all js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict"

    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
        const Bcolor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');




        if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");

                var colorv = 'orange';
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .title-bottom:before {background-color: red!important; } .mt-separator::before, .mt-separator:before, .mt-separator::after {background-color: red!important; }  .ulockd-btn-thm2:hover { background-color:cyan!important; }               .ulockd-btn-thm2 { background-color:brown!important; }                          .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:cyan!important; } .elementor-icon, .elementor-heading-title { color:red!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

                document.querySelectorAll(".ulockd-btn-white").forEach(function(node) {
                    node.classList.add("cssClass");
                });



                return false;
            });

            $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("color", "pink", "important");



                var colorv = 'orange';
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; }  .title-bottom:before {background-color: red!important; } .mt-separator::before, .mt-separator:before, .mt-separator::after {background-color: red!important; }  .ulockd-btn-thm2:hover { background-color:orange!important; } .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:orange!important; } .elementor-icon, .elementor-heading-title { color:red!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

                document.querySelectorAll(".ulockd-btn-white").forEach(function(node) {
                    node.classList.add("cssClass");
                });

                return false;
            });

        }

        if (Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
                document.querySelector(".ulockd-btn-white").classList.add("mystyle");

                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .colorful-buton-class > * > * > [role=button] { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:cyan!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

                return false;
            });

            $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "pink", "important");



                document.querySelector(".ulockd-btn-white").classList.add("mystyle");

                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; }  .colorful-buton-class > * > * > [role=button] { background-color:  orange!important ; }  .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:orange!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);


                return false;
            });

        }


    });

    $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
        if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "-195px"
            });
        }
    });

    $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});


jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" id="colors" href="http://hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/Hekim/widgets/css/colors/default.css" type="text/css" />');
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/Hekim/widgets/css/color-switcher.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Is there more info to improve the answer?

Comment: yes I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you execute a `forEach` on all elements in the document (selected by `document.querySelectorAll('*')`). There, you assign event listeners on elements selected by a common queries `$("ul.colors .color1")` and `$("ul.colors .color2")` (only if their computed styles accomplish some conditions). This way, each time user clicks on any `$("ul.colors .color1")` element, the event listener callback will be executed once for each element found in the first query `document.querySelectorAll('*')`. You probably don't want that.

I assume you want all elements in a page which matches some computed styles to change when the color picker changes its value.

First of all: once you change the color, the computed color will be different, so the condition matcher will change (and don't match anymore). So you want one of the next:

- Save/cache the affected elements (more efficient and less prone to errors)
- Automatically change the matching condition with the currently selected color

Then, this code may help with that:

```js
const colorMatchedElements = [...(document.querySelectorAll('*'))]
  .filter(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');

        return color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)'
  });
const BcolorMatchedElements = [...(document.querySelectorAll('*'))]
  .filter(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const Bcolor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

        return Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)'
  });

$("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
    colorMatchedElements.forEach( node => node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important") );
    BcolorMatchedElements.forEach( node => node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important") );

    // ...

    return false;
});

$("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
    colorMatchedElements.forEach( node => node.style.setProperty("color", "pink", "important") );
    BcolorMatchedElements.forEach( node => node.style.setProperty("background-color", "pink", "important") );

    // ...

    return false;
});
```

You can even improve this code, for example abstracting the click event on all colors, so it takes the selected value from the click event (for example).

#### Edit

Fixed a bug: `querySelector` return value is a `NodeList` type. You need to transform it into an `Array` to be able to use `filter` on it.